# Name of month and week of in Swift

Tags: swift, datetime, calendar

In Swift I need to get the month name and week of:

example: June 2 - 8

I have created an extension to Date() class and I do get the month name, but it is abbreviated and the weeks are printed out with Optional().

So I need for the week this.  2 - 8. I know the - can just be in a string literal so I am not worried about that.

```
extension Date {
    func monthAsString() -> String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMM")
        return df.string(from: self)
    }

    func startOfWeek() -> String? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))!
        return String(describing: gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday))
    }

    func endOfWeek() -> String? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))!
        return String(describing: gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: sunday))

    }
}
```

in a UILabel I need to show something like this:

June 2 - 8 or September 22 - 28

like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `"MMMM"`, not `"MMM"` to get the full month name.

Next, never use `String(describing:)` for anything except for debugging.

A better solution is to generate the two dates for start and end of week. Then use `DateIntervalFormatter` to generate a string from the two dates.

Here's your updated Date extension to generate Date instead of String:

```
extension Date {
    func startOfWeek() -> Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        if let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) {
            return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday)
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    func endOfWeek() -> Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        if let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) {
            return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: sunday)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an example showing how to use a `DateIntervalFormatter` to give the desired result:

```
let aDate = Date()
if let sow = aDate.startOfWeek(), let eow = aDate.endOfWeek() {
    let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
    formatter.dateTemplate = "MMMMd"
    print(formatter.string(from: sow, to: eow))
}
```

Output:

> September 9 - 15

Comment: Much simpler! Thank you very much!